# Using ViewModels in ASP.NET MVC 2 - multiple forms

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, viewmodel, multiple-forms

I couldn't find any documentation around using multiple forms in an ASP.NET MVC 2 ViewModel approach.

i.e. In the built in application when you select New MVC2 web app, the register page uses a ViewPage which inherits like this:

`Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<rs30UserWeb.Models.RegisterModel>"`

I wanted to use that approach on a page with multiple forms, but that RegisterModel only supported one form.

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specific of why you need multiple ViewModels?  There's a chance the new EditorFor is a more appropriate direction to go in? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1235646/asp-net-mvc-2-html-editorfor-and-custom-editortemplates

Comment: I have multiple forms on a single page.  I'm using the ASP.NET MVC2 model validation approach.

Comment: That first link I added wasn't particularly helpful, this is better http://blogs.msdn.com/nunos/archive/2010/02/08/quick-tips-about-asp-net-mvc-editor-templates.aspx

Answer (score 5):

The approach is to use a composite viewmodel:

```cs
namespace MyApp.Models
{
    public class MyCompositePageModel
    {
        public RegisterModel registerModel;
        public LoginModel loginModel;
    }
}
```

When you do that, inherit the View from it:

```cs
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<rs30UserWeb.Models.RegisterModel>" %>
```

Then reference the individual models in the page:

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.loginModel.Email) %>
<%= Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.loginModel.Email) %>
```

Hope someone else finds this useful.